# "Environment" VS "Milieu"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I see no difference between "environment" and "milieu" in the following example:

> - It is a study of the social and cultural **milieu** in which Michelangelo lived and worked. [[Source]](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/milieu)

I think, we can interchange the two words here in this example.

As Cambridge says, "milieu" is:

> The people, physical, and social conditions and events that provide the **environment** in which someone acts or lives.

This is my exact definition of "environment".

Are they interchangeable in this sense? 
Should I consider any point here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction made in [the answer by Old Brixtonian](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/249385/91457) is a quite subtle one. I do not thinmk that one could rely on most fluent speakers making the same exact distinction.

As a piratical matter, these words are in the specified context at least close to interchangeable. I would not rely on this difference in wording to convey a difference in meaning which was important to me.

Comment: What do you think of Javalatte's provided distinction @David Siegel? "**Milieu** describes the surroundings of **people**, whereas **environment** describes the surroundings of **anything**, including people."

Comment: @A-friend That is an interesting idea. I do not think most fuent speakers reliably make that distinction.

Answer (score 1):

They're not quite interchangeable. Maybe your exact definitions are different from the dictionary's!

[environment:](https://www.lexico.com/definition/environment) The surroundings or conditions in which a person, animal, or plant lives or operates.

[milieu](https://www.lexico.com/definition/milieu): A person's social environment.

As JavaLatte points out, "Milieu describes the surroundings of *people*, whereas environment describes the surroundings of anything, including people."

Comment: But I have come across both "social environment" and "social milieu" or "cultural / academic environment" or "cultural / academic milieu". Then I was wondering what is the difference between these terms?

Comment: "Social environment" means milieu. "Social milieu" is tautology, but perhaps it attempts to exclude from one's milieu anyone who isn't an actual friend. "Cultural / academic environment" means the architecture, art galleries, theatres, opera houses, concert halls, museums, libraries, pop venues, folk clubs, jazz clubs etc, etc.; the colleges, academies, universities etc. etc.; and the people working in, teaching in, studying at, visiting, attending etc. etc. the places I've mentioned; and the places where those people live, meet etc. Etc!

Comment: And "Cultural / academic milieu" means the PEOPLE mentioned in the last two lines of my previous comment! As I said, "Milieu describes the people, not the surroundings."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian "Milieu describes **the people**, not the surroundings"... this is perhaps misleading. Milieu describes the surroundings **of people**, whereas environment describes the surroundings **of anything**, including people.

Comment: @JavaLatte: Yes! Quite right. And well put. I lost the plot for a tick!  I've incorporated it. Thank you.